# A spaceship travelling to infinity while avoiding star collisions

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics, probability-theory, percolation

Consider placing countably infinitely many points labeled $S_i$ randomly over $\mathbb{R}^2$, with asymptotic density points/area $µ$.

Then, what is the largest $r$ such that we can find a a continuous curve with no finite square containing it, and such that all points $S_i$ have distance atleast $r$ to it?

And the same question for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You might be interested in Mean Free Path  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path

Comment: "Percolation" (with a 2D Poisson model, and considering the vacant space) would be the relevant keyword.

Comment: Gilbert disk model is a better keyword for anyone interested, I have personally lost interest in this problem.

Comment: There are bounds for when the discs have an infinite component, im not sure if this is the same as for the complement.